# virtual addresses confusion

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, architecture, x86-64

I was doing some research [48-bit Virtual Addresss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Virtual_address_space_details) but I am confused about how much memory can the lower and higher canonical halves address for the 48-bit implementation?

Also, does anyone know why the range of the lower and higher canonical half is is not continuous?

Answer (score 2):

Just put it in your calculator, 7fffffffffff = 140737488355327 = 140E12 ~= 140 terabytes.

I'd say that, other than mapping it that way being the traditional way in which the kernel and user-mode address spaces are separated, it helps to discourage programmers to abuse the unused bits in an address for their own use.